# Error: The configuration parameter "formElement" is a required for "costum_attribute" field

Tags: magento2, import, custom-attributes

I am trying to update a new custom boolean attribute for my products. I made a csv file with "additional attributes" column value like below:

disable_purchase=0,product_image_size=Default,sw_featured=No

disable_purchase=1,product_image_size=Default,sw_featured=No

I import this CSV by using the Magento default method, and everything looks fine, no error message.

However, when I go back to the catalog, I can't edit any of the product, when I click into a product, an error page occur with the following message:

---

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 424900644562

---

Then I checked the error report, find the following information:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:85:"The configuration parameter "formElement" is a required for "disable_purchase" field.";i:1;s:7643:"#0 
/home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(148): Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field->prepare()
#1 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field))
#2 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Container))
#3 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset))
#4 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(126): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form))
#5 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'product_form', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#6 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#7 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#8 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#9 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#10 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#11 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#13 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#14 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php(69): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#15 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit->execute()
#16 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#19 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#20 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#23 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#26 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#29 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#30 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#33 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#35 /home/kuohua/public_html/online-store/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#36 {main}";s:3:"url";s:122:"/online-store/kuohua_admin/catalog/product/edit/id/4/key/6660e84cbf8a6d0ab710febc06cdb1c9e9fdc4e29cfb60cecfe29e815765d3bc/";s:11:"script_name";s:23:"/online-store/index.php";}
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by information missing in the database.

Go to env_attribute in the database, find your custom attribute, and locate "frontend_input" column. Input value "select" into it. And everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creat a env_attribute with the code 
Then you have to go database and follow this steps:-

Step 1 :- Go to database

Step 2 :- find a table name env_attribute and then find a column frontend

Step 3 :- change a null value to text or you have to anything